# Why does the artwork look different before the OP plays?

Tags: usagi-drop

In the couple of minutes before the Opening plays in *Bunny/Usagi Drop* there seems to be a notifiable different in how the artwork is to the rest of the episode

Pre Opening

[image: Pre OP]
[image: Pre OP]

Post Opening

[image: Post OP]
[image: Post OP]

why is it that the artwork appears to be different like this?

Comment: Because that's how the director decided to direct it? I don't think there's really much of a "why" here.

Comment: Is that the first episode? What about the other episodes? Does the same art difference also occur in other episodes?

Comment: @AyaseEri I have watched the first 3 episodes and it occurs in all of them and the first 2 screenshots are not from the first 3 episodes so I would assume that it occurs in all of them

Comment: Wait, so, it really occurs in all of them or you just assume that it occurs? If it occurs consistently then it is like Senshin said. If not then maybe it was rushed due to time and/or financial constraint.

Comment: @AyaseEri having seen the entire series i can say it occurs in every episode. the first image posted is from the scene that occurs before the Opening in Episode 11 (when Rin discovers her first loose tooth)